# children prop in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am learning react at the moment. this is the link with the code - http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding what's going on in this part of the code

```
const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {
  if (active) {
    return <span>{children}</span>
  }

  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onClick()
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

Link.propTypes = {
  active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

I am having the most difficulty understand this snippet

```
return (
        <a
          href="#"
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            onClick()
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </a>
      )
    }
```

What does {children} mean here?
What does it do?

and what does this do?

```
children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
```

what is meant by node in the above line?

Comment: check the **doc**, very properly explained: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx **In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag, the content between those tags is passed as a special prop: props.children.**

Comment: ok, let me check

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use a Custom component, like

```
<MyComponent>Hello World</MyComponent>
```

Whatever you write between the tags (in above case Hello World) is passed to the component as a `children` prop.

So when write your component like

```
const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {
```

You are destructuring the props and getting only `active`, `children` and `onClick` from the props passed to the component

Consider for example, you call the `Link` component like

```
<Link active="true" onClick={someFunc} style={{color: 'orange'}}>Hello</Link>
```

Then amongst all the props i.e `active, onClick, style, children`, you will only be accessing `active, onClick,children` in the component.

For your second question:

> and what does this do?
>
> children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,

So here `PropTypes` is a way of performing a typeCheck on the props that are passed to the component. It is being imported from the `react-proptypes` package.

So

```
children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
```

makes the prop `children` to be required. So if your render your component like

```
<Link />
```

It will not pass the type check and hence you need to do

```
<Link>Text</Link>
```

Comment: ok thanks. this helps.
what I'd like to know is 

if (active) {
    return <span>{children}</span>
  }

so, in the above code, if it is active,
then {children} will be returned which is equal to 
All Active and completed. right?
or maybe it just returns the child which is active.
So, if All is active, then it returns All as disabled and we'll be unable to click
and for the rest, i.e. the 2nd return
it will show up as the active links??

but both of them are written as just {children}
and that's making me a bit confused.

Comment: So whatever is passed between link tags will be returned by {children} for an individual tag. So if you have three such tags, then each of them will return a different children based on the children prop and the active prop value

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
```

this is just the type checking of the react proptypes. Refer https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html for more details how type checking works.

According to the example this says that the prop children is required and is of type node. This type `node` refers to anything that can be rendered.  which is then included within the  tag in your rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the types of your props, you'd need to use `React.PropsWithChildren`, e.g.

```
type Props = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  name: string; // strongly typed!
  myProp: string;
}>;

export function MyComponent({ name, myProp, children }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <div>{myProp}</div>
      {children != null && children}
    </>
  )
}
```