# How to convert const reactjs component to class based

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to convert this code

```
const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

Into a class based component like this

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
      ....
  }
}
```

Normal const components I know how to convert, but I am not able to understand how to include `match` parameter in class based component.

Comment: `{ match }` would generally either map to `this.props.match` or `this.state.match` in a class based component when you are converting it. Depending on whether match is likely to change during the lifecycle of the component. If match is likely to change, make it a state variable, otherwise, make it a prop variable. Also, how you create the child component in the parent component will need to be reviewed in order to ensure you pass props or state correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your functional component definition

```
const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

The argument is the props passed down to the Child component, however when you use `{match}` you are detructuring only the prop match from all the props passed down.

See this answer: [What is the children prop in React component and what PropTypes do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734548/what-is-the-children-prop-in-react-component-and-what-proptypes-do/44734573#44734573)

So when converting your functional component to the class component you can `destructure` the prop `match` in the `render` function like

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
      var {match} = this.props;
      return (
         <div>
             <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
           </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**function:**

```
const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
)
```

**Class:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends Component {
  render(){
    const {match} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
         <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Child;
```