# how to change functional component to class component in react-sortable-hoc

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

how to change my `functional` component to `class` component my code is below

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(
  ({ items, SpeedGraph, StepLengthGraph, CadenceGraph, PaceGraph, graphPopupHandler}) => (
    <div>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={`item-${index}`}
          SpeedGraph={SpeedGraph}
          StepLengthGraph={StepLengthGraph}
          CadenceGraph={CadenceGraph}
          PaceGraph={PaceGraph}
          graphPopupHandler={graphPopupHandler}
          index={index}
          value={value}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
);
```

i try to change this code but not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert const reactjs component to class based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297329/how-to-convert-const-reactjs-component-to-class-based)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting React function component to class component issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695583/converting-react-function-component-to-class-component-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class components you need to implement `render` function and return your jsx from this function and access props using `this.props`

While in functional components you just return jsx directly from function and access props using first argument in that function

```
class SortableList extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { items, SpeedGraph, StepLengthGraph, CadenceGraph, PaceGraph, graphPopupHandler} = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={`item-${index}`}
          SpeedGraph={SpeedGraph}
          StepLengthGraph={StepLengthGraph}
          CadenceGraph={CadenceGraph}
          PaceGraph={PaceGraph}
          graphPopupHandler={graphPopupHandler}
          index={index}
          value={value}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297329/how-to-convert-const-reactjs-component-to-class-based?rq=1) (but I have too low rep to flag), and is pretty straightforward using the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). But here's a start:

```
class SortableList extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //any initialization here or in other react class methods
  }

  render() {
    const {items, SpeedGraph, StepLengthGraph, CadenceGraph, PaceGraph, graphPopupHandler} = this.props;
    return <div>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={`item-${index}`}
          SpeedGraph={SpeedGraph}
          StepLengthGraph={StepLengthGraph}
          CadenceGraph={CadenceGraph}
          PaceGraph={PaceGraph}
          graphPopupHandler={graphPopupHandler}
          index={index}
          value={value}
        />
      ))}
    </div>;
  }
}
```