# Unable to parse props in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement Presentational and Container Components pattern when creating React components. So I created a presentational component with only UI elements and container component with handling data capabilities.

#### component.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = ({props}) => (
<div>
{props.games.map((game, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    {game.index + 1} - {game.contestName}
  </div>
))};
</div>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

#### container.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyComponent from "./component";

class MyContainer extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  games: [
    {
      id: 1,
      categoryName: "Business/Company",
      contestName: "Name1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      categoryName: "Magazine/Newsletter",
      contestName: "Name2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      categoryName: "Software Component",
      contestName: "Name3"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      categoryName: "Website",
      contestName: "Name4"
    }
  ]
};
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <MyComponent games={this.state.games} />
  </div>
);
}
}

export default MyContainer;
```

However, I can not render data and I get

#### Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'games' of undefined.

Would really appreciate your help, as two days of internet digging has not yielded positive results.

Comment: This answer explains, the solution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734548/what-is-the-children-prop-in-react-component-and-what-proptypes-do/44734573#44734573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const MyComponent = ({props}) => (
```

When you do this, you actually do

`{ props: props-received-from-parent }`

You are enclosing your props in another object, remove those braces and change that line to

`const MyComponent = (props) => (`

and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, so much, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should destructure your `games` instead of `props`:

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = ({games}) => (
<div>
{games.map((game, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    {game.index + 1} - {game.contestName}
  </div>
))};
</div>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your MyComponent class like this

```
class MyComponent extends Component{

    render(){
        this.xyz = this.props.games.map((item,index) => {
            return(<div key={index}>{item.id}</div>)
        })
        return(
            <div>
                {this.xyz}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

This will also work!