# React - props is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have two components.

1. MypropDestructuring.jsx (main component)
2. MypropDestructuringMessage.jsx (using for prop destructuring) (I'm new for destructuring concept in React)

I think I am doing somewhere wrong in (MypropDestructuringMessage.jsx) props destructuring.

**On console log I am getting following error-**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined at
>   MypropDestructuringMessage.render (index.js:33930)

**Code:**

**MypropDestructuring.jsx**

```
// Let's import react
import React from "react";

// Import custom component
import MypropDestructuringMessage from "./MypropDestructuringMessage.jsx";


// Let's create component [[ MypropDestructuring ]]
class MypropDestructuring extends React.Component{

    // Let's create custom method
    _myProfile() {

        const myProfileData = [
            {
                id : 1,
                name : "Neon",
                age : 25,
                location : "UK",
                skill : "UI Dev"
            }
        ];

        // return
        return myProfileData.map( (profileArrg) => {

                return( 
                    <MypropDestructuringMessage key={profileArrg.id} name={profileArrg.name} age={profileArrg.age} location={profileArrg.location} skill={profileArrg.skill} /> 
                );
            }
        );

    }

    render(){

        const showProfile = this._myProfile();
        return(
            <section>

                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <h6> Prop Desturcturing </h6>
                <hr />

                <div>
                    {showProfile}
                </div>

            </section>
        );
    }
}


// Let's render ReactDOM
export default MypropDestructuring;
```

**MypropDestructuringMessage.jsx**

```
// Let's import react
    import React from "react";

    // Let's create component [[MypropDestructuringMessage]]
    class MypropDestructuringMessage extends React.Component{
        render(){


            // Props destructuring
            const {name, age, location, skill} = props;

            return(

                <section>

                    <div>
                        <ul className="list-group">
                            <li className="list-group-item"> {name} </li>   
                            <li className="list-group-item"> {age} </li>   
                            <li className="list-group-item"> {location} </li>   
                            <li className="list-group-item"> {skill} </li>    
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </section>
            );
        }
    }

    // Let's pass data with [[ propTypes ]] - object
    MypropDestructuringMessage.propTypes = {
        name : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age : React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        location : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        skill : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }


    // Let's render ReactDOM
    export default MypropDestructuringMessage;
```

Comment: You should do this.props

Comment: `profileArrg`is also undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `this.props` not only `props` :

```
const {name, age, location, skill} = this.props;
```

Here is the documentation on [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks Vivek, I am new for understanding destructuring. Can you share some document with examples on destructuring?

Comment: @Sandy, sure , updated the answer , please have a look.

Comment: @Sandy , you might wanna read this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734548/what-is-the-children-prop-in-react-component-and-what-proptypes-do/44734573#44734573

Answer (score 3):

Props are bound to context of the component (`this`), they are not global, that's why you're getting an error. Use `this.props` instead of `props`, unless you need to handle them in constructor, as in constructor this.props is still undefined. If you need props in constructor, they are sent as a parameter:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.props is not defined at this point, so you have to use props
    // do something with props here
}
```

You can read more on props in react [in this article](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic), it's useful for people new to React or ones who want to freshen up their knowledge, so check it out if you're interested!