# Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I cannot understand why **in the arrow functions** we do not need to wrap the literal of arrow function in the `({})` braces, instead of in this example the literal just wrapped in the single `()` braces. Why? I had surfed the internet to find an answer on it, but it failed.

And also why we put the arguments in double braces `({})`, instead of just `()`?

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => (
   <NavLink
       to={filter === 'SHOW_ALL' ? '/' : `/${ filter }`}
       activeStyle={ {
       textDecoration: 'none',
           color: 'black'
       }}
   >
       {children}
   </NavLink>
)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Using `({})` is to [`destructure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the arguments and `=> ()` is an implicit return equivalent to `=> { return ()}` and `(` only serves to disambiguate between the start of an object and the opening braces of a function body and would generally be used when you have a multiline return value. You could simply avoid using `(` and have the `NavLink` in the same line as the arrow `=>`

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => ( // <-- implicit return 
  <NavLink
    to={filter === 'SHOW_ALL' ? '/' : `/${ filter }`}
    activeStyle={ {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'black'
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </NavLink>
)
```

is equivalent to

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => {
   return (
      <NavLink
        to={filter === 'SHOW_ALL' ? '/' : `/${ filter }`}
        activeStyle={ {
          textDecoration: 'none',
          color: 'black'
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </NavLink>
    )
}
```

Check this answer for [more details on the usage of destructuring in `({ filter, children })`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734548/children-prop-in-react-component/44734573#44734573)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri so and what in my case `=> ()` do? You have give in your answer two separate point of views:
1. is an implicit return equivalent to `=> { return ()} `
2. `(` only serves to disambiguate between the start of an object and the opening braces of a function body.

Comment: @MaxWolfen, both are one and the same thing you can always write `const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => ( 
  <NavLink` or `const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => <NavLink`

Comment: @TomFenech That's not fully correct either. There is only an implicit return when it's single line. When curly brackets are used (multi line) an explicit return can be set. So, in other words, it's not an implicit return because the `=>` sign but because it's single line.

Comment: @GuyT to put my pedant hat on, that's not fully correct either, since we're talking about a single _expression_, not a line :^)

Comment: @Shubham rather than talk about "lines", maybe you should edit your answer to talk about "expressions".

Comment: @TomFenech Oops, I misinterpreted your previous comment, which is 100 percent correct. I will delete my 'reply' on it.

Comment: Is there any chance that this behavior get fixed? For example, I spent my last 5 minutes panicked because I remove parenthesis in `el => ({ a: 1 })`. Is there any obstacle to doing this?

Answer (score 31):

`const add = ( a, b ) => ( a + b )`

Is equivalent to

`const add = ( a, b ) => { return a+b; }`

When you use the `()` after your `=>` it just automatically returns the values inside.

**Edit:** you can also omit the `()` after `=>` entirely when its just a single line of return code, (thanks to [Tom Fenesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech)) as `()` is only needed with return code spanning across multiple lines.

Comment: No, the `(` after `=>` doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: @TomFenech indeed, it's the same as `=> a + b`. He should have placed `a + b` on next line to get the point across

Comment: To clarify even more for others: The above comments are talking about the `(` on the first line, because `const add = ( a, b ) => ( a + b )` can be written simply as `const add = ( a, b ) => a + b `. The `()` brackets are only really needed in a multi-line return, as @softcode said this could be better shown with a multi-line example. Updated the answer to reflect this.