# Making components with curly brackets versus parenthesis when using functional components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is the difference between using curly brackets and parenthesis whne making functional components in JSX. I have a components called layout which displays `props.children`

But i want to know if there is a difference or a best practise between when to use what, and for what purpose.

```
const layout = (props) => {
<Aux>
<div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
<main>
    {props.children}
</main>
</Aux>
}
```

versus

```
const layout = (props) => (
<Aux>
<div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
<main>
    {props.children}
</main>
</Aux>
)
```

Comment: Thie first shouldn't work because there is no `return`.

Comment: This was likely discussed numerous times on SO. It is specific to arrow function syntax, not React.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or/49425823#49425823)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the second snippet is correct. `=> (...)` is implicit arrow function return. Parentheses are there for readability *and* consistency with multiline explicit `return` statement. It could be:

```
const layout = (props) => 
  <Aux>
  ...
  </Aux>
```

With proper indentation and no parentheses a hanging indent makes function harder to read.

In order for the first snippet to work, there should be explicit arrow function return:

```
const layout = (props) => {
  return (
    <Aux>
    ...
    </Aux>
  )
}
```

Notice that parentheses are needed if `return` and `<Aux>` are on different lines.