# previous state in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Type 1:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
```

Type 2:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
<button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
```

Though the both above code give the same result, what exactly is difference between them and why 2nd method is preferred than the first one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is prevState in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

updating state is asynchronous so it is possible that there would be previous value in the "count" state when you're updating it again

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Type 2 has the latest value while Type 1 has the latest value since the last refresh. You'll notice if `setCount` is called multiple times before any refresh has occurred.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const someFunction => () => {
   console.log(count); //0
   setCount(count + 1); // count will be set to 1 on next refresh
   console.log(count); //still 0
   setCount(count + 1); // count will still be 1  on next refresh since count hasn't been refreshed
   console.log(count); //still 0
   setCount(c => c + 1); // count will be 2 on next refresh since c has the latest value
   console.log(count); //still 0
};
```