# Show/Hide elements of a list on click, one list item a time (react app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a list where, when you click on the title, it shows/hide the description below each one. It is partly working (when you click on a title, it shows all the descriptions and when you click again, it hides them all), but I need it to show/hide each item individualy.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import girl from '../assets/steps-image.png'
import arrow from '../assets/down-arrow.svg'

class StepsSection extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: true
    }
  }
render() {
  return (
    <StepsStyles  className="sections">
    <Illustration />
     <Content>
       <div><span className="tag">3 easy steps</span></div>
      <h1>How it works</h1>
```

Here we have the list:

```
      <ul>
        {Steps.map((lista, i)=>(
        <li key={i}>
        <div key={i} onClick={()=>{this.setState({show:!this.state.show})}} className="dropdown"><h2>{lista.title}</h2><img src={arrow} alt="" /></div>
        { this.state.show? <p>{lista.desc}</p> : null}
    </li>
        ))}
        
      </ul>
     </Content>
  </StepsStyles>
  )
}
}

export default StepsSection
```

This is just styled components:

```
const StepsStyles = styled.div`
  background: url(${girl}) no-repeat left;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: contain;  
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  display: grid;
  height: 50vh;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  /* max-height: 50vh; */
  h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
  }
`

  const Illustration = styled.div`
  grid: 1;
  `

  const Content = styled.div`
  grid: 2;
  text-align: left;
  img {
    max-width: 10px;
    max-height: 10px;
  }
  h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  ul{
    width: 60%;
  }
  li {
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--superlight-gray);
    ::last-child{
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    .dropdown {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
    }
  }
  `
```

And the json static data lays here on the bottom:

```
const Steps = [
    {
      title: '1. Download Tattoo master app (dropdown)',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world. '
    },
    {
      title: '2. Enter your location',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world.'
    },
    {
      title: '3. Find your tattoo master',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world.'
    }
  ]
```

here is the page: https://mastertattoo-landpage.netlify.app
and repo:https://github.com/micazev/mastertattoo-landpage

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use 3 different state variables to show and hide the description of steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this...

```
{Steps.map((lista, index) => (
  <details className='collapse'>
    <summary className='title'>{lista.title}</summary>
    <div className='description'>
      {lista.desc}
    </div>
  </details>
))}
```

details and summary are HTML tags for collapse.

Comment: perfect =) a simple and efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to change the state by the value in the state please pass a function to setState as first argument like this:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  show: !state.show
}));
```

Comment: the state is changing, but it opens all the <li> item once. I want it to open the item respective to the title the user is clicking. for example, if the person click on step number one, only the description hidden of the number 1 opens. right now I click on the number 1 and it opens all the hidden items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state for each one of your list elements. Then you can change them individually.

First I'd add an `id` to each one of the `Steps` item.

```
const Steps = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: '1. Download Tattoo master app (dropdown)',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world. '
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: '2. Enter your location',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world.'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: '3. Find your tattoo master',
      desc: 'Download the application in App Store and you acan find the wizard in any location around the world.'
    }
  ]
```

Second I'd change my `show` state to an Object. That way I can store the id of each item and them tell if it is `true` or `false`.

```
this.state = {
  show: {}
}
```

And finally I'd change the function to change each item state based on its `id`.

```
toggleListItem(itemId) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    show: {
      ...prevState.show,
      [itemId]: !prevState.show[itemId]
    }
  }))
}

<div key={lista.id} onClick={() => this.toggleListItem(lista.id)} className="dropdown"> ... </div>
```

You can see it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-browser-uxdr5

You can have a quick explanation about using `prevState` here:
[What is prevState in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs)