# having diffculty to empty the state in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hy, I'm working on react-native to integrate WebSocket. I'm setting the list state `const [messagesList, setMessagesList] = useState([])` when I set the messages in the list but facing an issue which is that **when I map the list on the second time it also display the pervious data**
like on first map it print

```
Hello Adil
How're you?
```

when I get the new data it also map it again:

```
Hello Adil // first map
How're you? // first map
//second map
Hello Adil
How're you?
new message
new message
```

I want my old messages to remain on-screen but don't display them again on the screen
here's the code:
**Setting the state**

```
 setMessagesList((messagesList)=>[...messagesList,{'msg':type,'user':data.text}])
```

**map the messageList**

```
messagesList.map((msg,index)=>{
      return(
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:msg.user == 'adilijaz.09@gmail.com' ? 'flex-start' : 'flex-end'

        }} > 
        <Text>{msg.msg}--{msg.user}</Text>
      </View> 
      )
      })
```

Comment: this might have been an answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs

Comment: can you check if your setMessagesList is getting called more than once?

Comment: I think you should show how you are calling setMessagesList()

Comment: @AmitChauhan its calling when receive new message or send the message

Comment: @AdilIjaz one of reason for it's getting called twice is if you have added listener to your socket twice. So if you can just put console log in that or show your entire relevant code.

Comment: Can you please share the flow of your source code so i can try to sort out your issue ?