# React Hooks - Prevent re-render when using prevState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to be able to conditionally set a state based on previous state changes with React Hooks. But if the state remains the same the component shouldn't re-render.

When using class components, I was able to achieve this using:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
   if(prevState.value !== true) {
     return { value: true }
   }

   return null
})
```

The code above sets the state to `true`, only if it's not `true`. However, if it's already `true`, **the component doesn't re-render**. I would like to achieve the same effect with React Hooks.

I know that with React Hooks, I can use the `prevState` like this:

```
setValue(prevValue => {
   // some code
   return newValue
})
```

However, I don't know how to prevent re-render if the state remains the same. Is it possible for me to prevent render after using React Hooks `prevState`? Thank you for your concern.

Comment: `if (!state.value) setState({ value: true });`?

Comment: @Andy Thank you for your suggestion. I am currently using this. However, as far as I know, it's not the best practice because it can lead to incorrect results. Here is a link about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807520/8318855. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: If your state is only one object with one property of `value` you can use it. If not `if (!state.value) setState({ ...state, value: true });` may be better so you preserve all the other properties in state.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your component by memo

```js
import { useEffect, useState, memo } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("re-rendered");
  });

  const setTestToTrue = () => {
    setTest((v) => {
      if (v !== true) return true;
      return v;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={setTestToTrue}>Set test to true</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Use of pure components using life cycle hooks or useMemo in React Hooks.
2. shouldComponentUpdate() use the change of state login inside this hook.