# change state with prevState

Tags: reactjs, state

I need help understanding prevstate. I've read [what is prevstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs), [reac-prevstate](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-prevstate/86495/13), and [state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). But I still don't get it.

```
export default function SignInUp(props) {
  const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false)
  const { handleLogin, handleRegister } = props

  const toggleState = () => {
    setToggleClass(!prevState)
  }

  return (
    <div className='UserContainer' style={{display: "grid", justifyContent: "center ", height: "100vh", width: "100vw"}}>
      <div className='btncontainer' style={{gridRow: "2 / 3"}}>
        <button onClick={toggleState} className='togglebtn' style={{background: "none", border: "none"}}>Signin</button>
        <button onClick={toggleState} className='togglebtn' style={{background: "none", border: "none"}}>Signup</button>
      </div>
      <SignIn handleLogin={handleLogin} className={toggleClass ? 'Disabled' : null} style={{gridRow: "2 / 3" }}/>
      <SignUp handleRegister={handleRegister} className={toggleClass ? 'Disabled' : null}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enqueueing state updates it is common to access the previous state's value in order to compute the next state. Take the counter example.

> ```
> /**
>    * count +3 click handler using naive state updates.
>    */
>   const clickHandler1 = () => {
>     // assume count equals some number n
>     setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
>     setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
>     setCount(count + 1); // update queued, count === n, count = n + 1
>     // when processed the count will be n + 1
>   };
>
>   /**
>    * count +3 click handler using functional state updates.
>    */
>   const clickHandler2 = () => {
>     // assume count equals some number n
>     setCount((count) => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 0, count = prevCount + 1
>     setCount((count) => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 1, count = prevCount + 1
>     setCount((count) => count + 1); // update queued, count === n + 2, count = prevCount + 1
>     // now when processed each call uses the result of the previous update
>     // count will be n + 1 + 1 + 1, or n + 3
>   };
> ```

[image: Edit react - regular and functional state updates]

If you were to simply enqueue several "standard" state updates, then each update overwrites the previous update. ***But*** if you were to use "functional" state updates, these access the previous state and return a new state value.

The difference is updating from the previous state's value versus updating from the previous render cycle's state value.

For toggling values, each *next* state **necessarily** depends on the *previous* state, in order to be toggled correctly.

```
const toggleState = () => {
  setToggleClass(toggleValue => !toggleValue);
}
```

This takes the previous state, assigns it to a variable named `toggleValue` and returns the negation of this value as the next state value.

Comment: Exactly, the reason is that setState is asynchronous, and you cannot guarantee the moment this is executed. For that you need to pass a callback in order to get the previous state at the actual moment the setState is being executed.

Comment: @SoniaAguilar It's technically more accurate to say `setState` is synchronous and it's React batching and processing the state updates asynchronously. Think of `setState` as a request to React to update state at the next earliest convenience.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense seeing it like this!

Comment: I agree, @DrewReese. You're right, thank you!