# Callback function placement in setState()

Tags: reactjs

Whats the difference between

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {value:prevState.value+1}},callback)
```

vs

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {value:prevState.value+1}},()=>{callback})
```

I am getting old state in 1st type of setState() in callback function e.g console.log(this.state.value) is printing old state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is prevState in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807454/what-is-prevstate-in-reactjs)

Comment: @AmanSadhwani No, actually I know about prevstate, I just used () instead of passing prevState, I am just confused passing a function to call back parameters. 1st one is accessing old state,2nd one is accessing new updated state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {value:prevState.value+1}},()=>{callback})
```

In the above code, you're using an anonymous function to wrap `callback`, but `callback` is not triggered as you expected.

If you want to trigger `callback`, you need to make it like `callback()`

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {value:prevState.value+1}},()=>{callback()})
```

---

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {value:prevState.value+1}},callback)
```

This is different. You pass `callback` as a parameter directly, and the callback will be executed in `setState` internally.

---

To clarify more how `setState` calls `callback` internally, I'd show you a small demo.

```js
const setState = (state, callback) => {
   //TODO: The logic for state
   //and then execute callback
   callback()
}

setState({}, () => console.log('Callback here'))
```

Comment: Can you explain why callback will be executed in setState internally in the first case?

Comment: You can check my updated answer with a small demo @a2nineu

Comment: Thank you so much but why console.log will show us old state if we dont wrap it around anonymous function?

Comment: because the anonymous function gets triggered (not `callback` function). If you want to trigger `callback`, you need to explicitly execute it `callback()` @a2nineu