# What does `((prevState: null) => null) | null` mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

If I have this code:

```
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";
export default function Test() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null); 
  setState('string');
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: null) => null'.deno-ts(2345)
```

I understand that it expects me to use the same value type of the initial type. However if the initial value is an actual literal like number:

```
-   const [state, setState] = useState(null); 
+   const [state, setState] = useState(1);
```

Then the error is:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | ((prevState: number) => number)'.deno-ts(2345)
```

Reading [What is prevState in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54807454/3416774) or [Hooks – Preact Guide](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#usestate) doesn't help me understand:

- What does `((prevState: null) => null) | null` mean?
- Why is the first case the required type not `null | ((prevState: null) => null)`?
- How can I use multiple type? For example, the initial value is 1 or null, but I then set the value to `'string'` afterward?

Comment: If you initialise the state as null, you will need to tell typescript what sort of values that state can hold in future `useState<number | null | string | anyTypeThisMightBe>(null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is partly answered, I think your second question is still not answered. So I will still submit this one:

Answer to the three questions:

1. React expects either a new state value or a state updater function. So since the type of your state is inferred to be `null`, TS compiler is simply complaining that it would either expect `null` (new state value) or `((prevState: null) => null) | null` (state updater function). This method should return a new value based on the previous value. [Doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate)
2. `null` type in [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) is usually merged into other types.

Look at the below code.

```
let x : null| number  = 'string';
```

The error is **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.** and not **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | null'.**

[image]

Now if we write something like the below:

```
let y : null  = 'string';
```

The error will be:

[image]

As you can see there is no omitting of `null` as there is no union.

[Playground Link for the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ssl=3&ssc=26&pln=3&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAHhBcEDsCuxgB9FILYCMQCcIIBeCAcgGcx8BLBAczIG4AoF0SATzk1SNMrU6jVkA)

This is a trivial example of what is happening above. And when the code is changed to:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(1);
```

The error is as expected and now includes the `number` part of the union:

`'number | ((prevState: number) => number)'`

3. For multiple types, as mentioned in the comments, just use something like a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) and you are good:

```
const [val,setVal] = useState<number | null | string | boolean>(null)
```

**Edit:**
If you are keen on getting `null` in your error, depending on the version of TS involved you can tweak it.

The below playground is using TS `4.x.x`, and I can enable/disable `strictNullChecks` by clicking on TS Config button. Once you enable `strictNullChecks`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/DYUwLgBAHhBcEDsCuBbARiAThAPopwwEAvBAORRkDcQA)

`strictNullChecks` does what it says. It starts including `null` ( and `undefined`) in your checks (in this case a union)

[Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)

Answer (score 4):

`((prevState: null) => null) | null` means you can call the state setter function with an updater callback (where the previous state is `null` and the returned value of the callback is also `null`) or you can pass it `null` directly.

Example: `setState(null)` or `setState((prev) => null)`.

The order of these two options in the type definition is unimportant.

To allow more than one type to be held in that state, you need to be explicit in your definition. Without passing a type, the type will be inferred by the initial value. Your initial value is `null` so the inferred type is `null` and nothing else.

To allow a string or null, you can use `const [state, setState] = useState<null | string>(null);`

The resulting type definition would be (at least close to) `((prevState: null | string) => null | string) | null | string`

Comment: why is it that in the null case it does not expect me to pass a null directly, and in the second case it does expect me to pass a number?

Comment: I misunderstood that portion of the question. Looks like you have an answer to that piece as well now