# Role of () bracket after arrow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

This line works as the content after arrow in wrapped in ()

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({toggle:prevState.toggle + 1}))
```

The content after arrow is not wrapped in () so it is not working

```
this.setState((prevState) => {toggle:prevState.toggle + 1})
```

Comment: This is really to do with the JS arrow function, it's not exclusive to React.

Comment: Maybe this answers it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or/49425823#49425823

Answer (score 4):

Arrow functions may implicitly return values by simply omitting the
curly braces that traditionally wrap a function's body if their body
only contains a single expression.

```
const foo = x => x + 1;
foo(1); // -> 2
```

When using implicit returns, object literals must be wrapped in parenthesis so that the curly braces are not mistaken for the opening of the function's body.

```
const foo = () => { bar: 1 } // foo() returns undefined
const foo = () => ({ bar: 1 }) // foo() returns {bar: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to implicitly return an object, curly braces do not work because they denote start and end of block. In order to distinguish between block and JS object, you wrap the object in ().