# Unexpected error upon making a Query to GraphQL server from React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jsx

I am getting an error:
**Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression** at the **Query Tag** and second at the **div** inside my map function, when I am making a query to the backend GraphQL server.

Here is my query.component.jsx file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo';
import {gql} from 'apollo-boost';

const GET_COMMUNITY = gql`
    query Community {
        Community {
        isOpen
        member_count
        name
        description
        }
    }
`;

const TestQuery = () => {
    <Query query={GET_COMMUNITY}>
        {
            ({loading,error, data:{Community}}) => {
                if(loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
                if(error) return <h1>Error occured...</h1>;
                return (
                    Community.map((item) =>{
                        <div className="community_members">
                        <p>{item.isOpen}</p>
                        <p>{item.member_count}</p>
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>
                        <br />
                        </div>
                    })
                );
            }
        }
    </Query>
};
export default TestQuery;
```

Is this error because of the map function that I have used??
Please help me out on how to solve these types of issues as finding bugs in React Codes become a bit difficult as compared to other languages/frameworks.

Comment: try to rename `Community` into `community`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not returning the value inside map which is why you get this error.

Either you use an explicit return like below

```js
return (
    Community.map((item) =>{ 
     return (    // return statement here
        <div className="community_members">
        <p>{item.isOpen}</p>
        <p>{item.member_count}</p>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.description}</p>
        <br />
        </div>
      )
    })
);
```

or an implicit return like

```js
return (
    Community.map((item) => ( // Implicit return
        <div className="community_members">
        <p>{item.isOpen}</p>
        <p>{item.member_count}</p>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.description}</p>
        <br />
        </div>
      )
   )
);
```

please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or/49425823#49425823) for information on the above syntaxes