# How can I generate an object from an array where the keys are the words and the values are the string lengths?

Tags: javascript, key-value

```
const myArray = ["hello", "hi", "beep", "boop", "cromulent"];

var lengths = myArray.map(function(word){
 return word.length
}) 

Object.entries(myArray);
console.log(myArray + lengths);
```

How can I take the array myArray and instead of it printing:

> "hello,hi,beep,boop,cromulent5,2,4,4,9"

Print the strings as keys and the values as the lengths. I was thinking of using a foreach loop, or a for of loop, but I don't know how to set the keys and values.

So in the end it would look like:

> {hello :5, hi :2, beep :4, boop :4, cromulent :9}

Comment: `var lengths = myArray.reduce((a, x) => ({...a, [x]: x.length}), {});`

Answer (score 2):

Either type of loop will work just fine. Here's an example with a forEach.

```js
const myArray = ["hello", "hi", "beep", "boop", "cromulent"];

var obj = {};
myArray.forEach(function(i){
  obj[i] = i.length;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of what Dinh Carabus said, you can use ES6's `Array.prototype.reduce()` method.

```js
const myArray = ["hello", "hi", "beep", "boop", "cromulent"];
let lengths = myArray.reduce((a, x) => ({
  ...a,
  [x]: x.length
}), {});
```

Being a person who rarely uses arrow functions, I had to do a bit of searching to find out how that syntax actually *works*. If you, too have a hard time comprehending that, I converted it to use `function()` instead of arrow functions:

```js
let lengths = myArray.reduce(function(a, x){
    return {
        ...a,
        [x]: x.length
    }
}, {});
```

It is always a good idea to explain, so let's review this shall we?

`Array.prototype.reduce` takes 2 parameters, a function and an initial value to pass in.

Passing in the initial value allows you to reduce it into an object. In this case, we pass in an object to add into it until we are all done with iterating over our array.

As for the function, we are using two parameters - the previous value the function returned  and the current value.
The spread operator adds all of the values before it, and you are adding to the object the current value you are on as the key ("x") and the length ("x.length").

I, myself was surprised something as efficient as this exists.

Of course, `forEach` or a `for` loop works perfectly fine, too - as another answer has demonstrated.

Sources I used:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp (although [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) has a great documentation on it, too)
- [Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or)
- [Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or)
- https://codebeautify.org/jsviewer (to beautify the code that was initially provided for scrutinization)
- https://typeofnan.dev/beware-the-reduce-spread-operator-combination/

In addition, I also decided to write a function for y'all that takes an array and returns an object with the value as its key and the length of the string as its value:

```js
function reduceArray(array){
  return array.reduce((a, x) => ({
    ...a,
    [x]: x.length
  }), {});
}
console.log(reduceArray(["hello","world!"]));
```