# When do I include parenthesis when passing state into setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, arrow-functions

Shown below is a snippet of the declaration of a function in my react component:

```
increment() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      count: state.count + 1
    }));
  }
```

Notice that there is parenthesis right after the arrow.
I do not understand why this code wouldn't work without the parenthesis, since it wasn't required in another similar case:

```
toggleVisibility() {
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.visibility === true) {
         return { visibility: false };
       } else {
         return { visibility: true };
      }
    });
  }
```

**When do I use the parenthesis?**

I'm a new self-learn coder, please be kind on me! Many thanks.

Comment: It's nothing specific to setState. [See the advanced syntax for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax). In the context of an arrow function, curly brackets might mean an object or they might mean a function body. The syntax of javascript is such that if you want to make it to mean an object, you wrap it in parentheses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a react thing, it's a javascript syntax. Using parenthesis is a shortcut for returning an object.

For example,

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const withParenthesis = items.map((item) => ({item}));

// is the same with
const withoutParenthesis = items.map((item) => {
  return {item};
})
```

Keep in mind that you need to `manually` return when not using `({})`