# Calling a function in Arrow Function

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I just wanted to know how does this work, if I have an `onChange()`

```
onChange={() => input()}
```

The above code immediately executes the input function when `onChange()` is triggered.

But what about this, how does this work?

```
onChange={() => input}
```

Even when `onChange` is triggered the input function is not being called.

What is the difference between these two statements?

Comment: The first version works because you declare an arrow function and provide that as the change handler. When the change event fires, the arrow function runs and it contains an invocation of `input()`, so that then runs. In the second example, you have the same arrow function assigned to the change handler, however you've only got a single statement there which is a *reference* to the `input` function, and will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: that's not valid JS, give us more context/code : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

Comment: `() => input()` is a function that, when called, calls `input()`. `() => input` is a function that, when called, does nothing except return the `input` object. — Hint: `input` just by itself would also be a function that, when called, well, calls `input()`.

Comment: `onChange={input}` should do what the first example does.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it is valid in React context.

Comment: @SalmanA that's not true, in your example the parameter from `onChange` is passed to `input`, where in OP's first example, no paramaters are passed.

Comment: @0stone0 then `reactjs` tag should be set

Comment: `() => input()` is like `() => {return input()}`, whereas `() => input` is like `() => {return input}` the input is never called from inside the arrow function, but it becomes the return value of the arrow function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a reference to the `input` function where as `input()` executes the `input` function and returns the value.

So when you call an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without explicit brackets (`{}`), the value is automatically returned.

- [Arrow functions and the use of parentheses () or {} or ({})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425755/arrow-functions-and-the-use-of-parentheses-or-or)

---

So `onChange={() => input}` will get the *reference* of the `input` function, where as `onChange={() => input()}` will get the return value of the `input` function.

---

Someone recommended `onChange={input}` in the comments, this will automatically pass all the parameters given to `onChange` (like the DOM event) to the `input` function, keep that in mind an this equivalent to `onChange={(e) => input(e)}`

This is fine for `onChange` of (eg) an `<input>` element, but one common mistake is by using the `parseInt` function, if you pass all the arguments to that, it will use it as base and give unexpected output:

```js
const a = ['1','2','3'].map(parseInt);                      // WRONG
const b = ['1','2','3'].map((num) => parseInt(num, 10));    // GOOD

console.log(a, b)
```

```json
[
  1,
  NaN,
  NaN
] 
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

- [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)

---

React demo showing the 4 cases shown above, please see the comments in the code regarding the working

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('Type!');
    
    const input = (e = false) => {
        const newVal = (e)
            ? e.target.value
            :'Nothing passed to input()';

        setValue(newVal);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {/* OK: event is automaticly passed */}
            <input onChange={input} value={value} />
            
            {/* NO: function not called */}
            <input onChange={() => input} value={value} />
            
            {/* NO: event NOT passed to input function */}
            <input onChange={() => input()} value={value} />
            
            {/* OK: event is manually passed to function */}
            <input onChange={(e) => input(e)} value={value} />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```